# matplotlib parameter 'edgecolor' does not work with quiver?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The [matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html) docs state that:

> **Arrow outline**
>
> *linewidths* and *edgecolors* can be used to customize the arrow outlines

However, a simple test code shows that `edgecolor` apparently does nothing. Am I missing something?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(-3, 3, 1)
Y = np.arange(-3, 3, 1)
U, V = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V, edgecolor='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems `linewidth` parameter is set to 0 as default for `plt.quiver`. Adding some sort of value in the function call starts displaying the edges of arrows. I.e.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(-3, 3, 1)
Y = np.arange(-3, 3, 1)
U, V = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V, edgecolor='r', linewidth = 1)
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Well that was definitely unintuitive. No idea how you thought of trying this but thank you!

Comment: Yup they could mention that somewhere in the documentation.